# laravel4 data is not inserting in a single field

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I have a database Namely "Marriages" and an user can insert his Marital information and that inserted values stored in this database.Here i have several fields including **present address**.

But in **present address** the posted data is not inserting though other posted data is inserting in the associated field,after a lots of research i can not figure out the problem.Here is my files.

**Migration** :

```
Schema::create('marriages', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->boolean('approved')->default(false);
        $table->string('candidate_name',255)->unique();
        $table->string('email',255)->unique();
        $table->string('father_name',60);
        $table->string('mother_name',60);
        $table->date('date_of_birth');
        $table->string('sex',60);
        $table->string('location',255);
        $table->string('blood_group',20);
        $table->string('religion',60);
        $table->string('present_address',255);
        $table->string('permanent_address',60);
        $table->string('height',100)->nullable();
        $table->string('complexion',100);
        $table->string('nationality',100);
        $table->string('educational_qualification',255);
        $table->string('occupation',255);
        $table->integer('phone_number');
        $table->integer('number_of_bro_sis');
        $table->string('image',255);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**Controller**:

```
public function postMarriageInfo()
{
   $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(),array
    (
        'candidate_name' => 'required',
        'father_name'=> 'required',
        'mother_name' => 'required',
        'date_of_birth' => 'required',
        'present_address' => 'required',
        'permanent_address'=> 'required',
        'educational_qualification' => 'required',
        'height' => 'required',
        'location' => 'required',
        'complexion' => 'required',
        'nationality' => 'required',
        'occupation' => 'required',
        'number_of_bro_sis' => 'required',
        'religion' => 'required',
        'sex' => 'required',
        'blood_group' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        'phone_number' => 'required',
        'image' => 'required',
    ));

   if($validator->fails()){
        return Redirect::route('marriage-form')
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->withInput()
                ->with('global','There is an error,currently data is not posting!');            
   }
   else
   {
     //get Matrimonial Information

    //Session::flash('it is working');

    $file = Input::file('image');
    $image_name = $file->getClientOriginalName();

    $file_path = $file->move(public_path().'/uploads/marriage_images',$image_name);

    $name = Input::get('candidate_name');
    $father_name = Input::get('father_name');
    $mother_name = Input::get('mother_name');
    $date_of_birth = Input::get('date_of_birth');
    $present_address = Input::get('present_address');
    $permanent_address = Input::get('permanent_address');
    $location = Input::get('location');
    $educational_qualification = Input::get('educational_qualification');
    $height= Input::get('height');
    $complexion = Input::get('complexion');
    $nationality = Input::get('nationality');
    $occupation = Input::get('occupation');
    $num_of_bro_sis = Input::get('number_of_bro_sis');
    $religion = Input::get('religion');
    $sex = Input::get('sex');
    $blood_group = Input::get('blood_group');
    $email = Input::get('email');
    $phone_number = Input::get('phone_number');
    //$image = Input::file('image');
    //$destinationPath = 'uploads';

   //   $image_name = $image->getClientOriginalName();
    //$image_upload = $image->move($destinationPath,$image_name);


    $marriage_info = Marriage::create(array(
            'candidate_name' => $name,
            'father_name' => $father_name,
            'mother_name' => $mother_name,
            'date_of_birth' => $date_of_birth,
            'present_address' => $present_address,
            'permanent_address' => $permanent_address,
            'location' => $location,
            'educational_qualification' => $educational_qualification,
            'height' => $height,
            'complexion' => $complexion,
            'nationality' => $nationality,
            'occupation' => $occupation,
            'number_of_bro_sis' => $num_of_bro_sis,
            'religion' => $religion,
            'sex' => $sex,
            'blood_group' => $blood_group,
            'email' => $email,
            'phone_number' =>$phone_number,
            'image' => $image_name
        ));

    if($marriage_info){

        return Redirect::route('marriage-form')
                ->with('global','You have Successfully Registered!');
    }

   }
```

}

**Template**(Only the Present Address Field):

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Present Address</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                     <textarea 
                      class="form-control" rows="3" name="present_address"{{(Input::old('present_address')) ? ' value="'.e(Input::old('present_address')).'"' : ''}}>
                     </textarea>
                            @if($errors->has('present_address'))
                            <span style="color:red;">
                            {{$errors->first('present_address')}}
                            </span>
                            @endif
                </div>

</div>
```

**Model**:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class Marriage extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {



    public function getRememberToken()
    {
        return $this->remember_token;
    }

    public function setRememberToken($value)
    {
        $this->remember_token = $value;
    }

    public function getRememberTokenName()
    {
        return 'remember_token';
    }

    protected $fillable=array
    (   'candidate_name',
        'father_name',
        'mother_name',
        'date_of_birth',
        'present_adddress',
        'permanent_address',
        'educational_qualification',
        'height',
        'location',
        'complexion',
        'nationality',
        'occupation',
        'number_of_bro_sis',
        'religion',
        'sex',
        'blood_group',
        'email',
        'phone_number',
        'image'
    );

    protected $table='marriages';


    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;
```

}

i am really confused why only the **present address** data is not inserting.If you see any issues in my code,please let me know.

Comment: Not sure about the issue but why double code for same thing, you may use directly `'present_address' => Input::get('present_address')` instead.

Comment: Also make sure that you have `present_address` in the form.

Comment: I have present address field in my form for sure. @The Alpha

Comment: And I am also making sure that each time i am passing present address @The Alpha

Comment: @Rego did you add `present_address` to your model `$fillable` array? Can you share model code?

Comment: yeah i am checking my model. @ARIFMAHMUDRANA

Comment: i have got it,there was a spelling mistake of the present address word  in my model,many thanks  @ARIFMAHMUDRANA to remind me about the model,i have forgotten to check my model file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever insert, update in laravel you have add `$fillable` array in laravel eloquent model check this for more details http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: i have added my Model file.